# Maximum number of output series (64) was reached or not but with the same number of plot functions? How to understand this?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have ~64 plot functions and practically don't add more. But their the colors are connected to Boolean variables. For example if the Boolean variable is `true` then the color is `red` but if `false` then its `green` (or sometimes transparent, `fill` functions have the main role then).

The interesting is,

- If I say `BooleanVariable = false` then we don't exceed that limit of 64.
- If I say `BooleanVariable = true` then again, we don't exceed that limit of 64.
- But if I say `BooleanVariable = some_boolean_math_expression` the result of which is sometimes true, sometimes false, then whoops; limit is exceeded.

I am confused because the expression may return with `true` or `false`, one of the other cases when the limit is not exceeded. It's like the script hates math (returning with `true` or `false` values) but accepts direct declarations of `true` or `false` values.

Is it a bug? Or a strange but understandable logic somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using boolean expressions results in the output being an additional output series. For example if you use a boolean expression to define the color of a plot then it results in two of the 64 limit being used, even though only one plot() is used.

```
c = close > open
plot(close, color = c ? color.green : color.red)
```

Comment: Very interesting. If a `plot()` has two boolean expressions (one in the `series` and one in the `color` parameter), would that result in 4 of the 64 being used?

Comment: I don't believe so, a boolean expression for the series argument should still only use one of the output series limit, or two if there is a boolean expression in in the color argument.

Comment: Practically, there's a Boolean to switch the plot ON or OFF and another Boolean for the color. I observed this thing and it was 1 slot for one plot with this configuration. :) It's interesting why it consumes even 1 slot from the 64 when only the color is being altered. Couldn't it be simple to raise the limit to e.g. 256? That's still 8-bit. 64 GB RAM I have, it should be enough (in case the memory capacity is the crucial). :D

Comment: Well, it really should be increased from 64, as I see now. I had a bunch of plotchars and labels but disabled all of them just for the sake of these colored marks (commented'em out), even so I'm near that 64. There's five Bollinger Bands, the color of each line of them is connected to a Boolean variable, and I should do the same with VWAP's line and bandlines and that leads to the extent yet. :) It reminds me to the well-known Bill Gates anecdote that "640 KByte must be enough".  

It's an indicator I develop for everyone which should not be two separated indicators, you know.   Anyways…

Comment: I'm surprised they even put a limit on this, they should really increase it to 128

Answer (score 2):

I proved @rumpy's answer is correct.

When I have this line I encounter the error:

```
plotchar(sellSetup==4, title='Sell Setup 4', char='4', color=setupColor(color.green, sellSetup))
```

then I refactor it like

```
plotchar(sellSetup==4, title='Sell Setup 4', char='4', color=color.new(color.green, 59))
```

The error is gone.

Conclusion:
`color` must be constant, otherwise it will increase the plot count

Answer (score 1):

I replace several `plot` with labels to allow more drawings